# PHP - Upload de arquivo em pastas diferentes

Tags: php, file-upload

Tenho que fazer um script em PHP que envie um único arquivo upado para várias pastas (listadas em na raiz do servidor dinamicamente). O problema é que o primeiro upload é realizado sem problemas, depois não consigo enviar para as demais pastas.

```
EXEMPLO:

$dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$scandir = scandir($dir);

$pastas = array();
foreach ($scandir as $pasta) {
    if($pasta == "." || $pasta == ".." || $pasta == ".htaccess" || $pasta == "default.htmlx" || $pasta == "error_log") {

    } else {
        $pastas[] = $pasta;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    foreach ($pastas as $key => $pasta) {
        $arquivo = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $desired_dir = $dir."/".$pasta."/sistema/engine/";
        $caminho = $desired_dir.$arquivo;       

        $upload = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $caminho);
        if(!$upload) {
            echo "Erro ao realizar upload em: ".$caminho;
            exit(0);      
        }
    }

    echo "Deu certo.";
    exit(0);
}
```

Alguém sabe aonde posso estar errando ou se existe alguma restrição de upload no foreach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você usa `move_uploaded_file()` você pega o arquivo que foi salvo temporariamente e move ele para um outro lugar, se usar outra vez, irá mover o arquivo novamente, mas sempre um único arquivo.
Para criar um outro arquivo utilize o copy, porém, use o move_upload_file() primeiro para ter as checagens que o mesmo faz.
Exemplo:

```
move_uploaded_file($arquivo_temp, $destino1);
copy($destino1, $destino2);
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Excelente, Lucas! Deu certinho. Obrigado pela ajuda e pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: Cara 4 anos depois e a sua resposta me salvou!